# Enabling External Object Beta in My Developer Org

Tags: lightning-connect

I would like to enable the External Object Beta in my developer org. Does this require a case with Salesforce support?

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Timothy! To get the most of your experience here, please visit [help] to take our Tour and review the posting guidelines. I've edited your question to remove the sig line to conform with what's expected when posting here.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not there now, yes, though it might be enabled when the Org is upgraded to API 32, since EDO goes GA then. Or you can [sign up](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter15.jsp) for a pre-release dev org right now - mine has EDO enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked in my Winter 15 org that I created for use during Dreamforce. It has appeared under `Build > Develop > External Objects`

[image]